# layout XML issues in Android

Tags: android

I am trying out a very simple rectangle box with two icons in the center. Strangely they are not coming up properly even after I add gravity etc. Please take a look at the screen shot.

[image]

I am trying center them so that they look perfectly in the center.

Here is the code I am trying out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/panelcolor"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/accountsNameandImage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/accountsNameandImage2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/accountsNameandImage1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Viewed"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the two LinearLayouts on a RelativeLayout with             `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and delete the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` from the LinearLayout with id *accountsNameandImage1*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/panelcolor" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/accountsNameandImage1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/homeImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/homeName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/accountsNameandImage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/accountsNameandImage1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/viewImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Viewed"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/panelcolor"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/accountsNameandImage1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_home" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/homeName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/accountsNameandImage2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/viewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Viewed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```